# Mapping multi-key shortcut involving Super_L in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, remapping

I recently moved from Mac as my primary workstation to Ubuntu. And it has been a struggle... which I found to be surprising because before moving to Mac (5 years ago) I was on Ubuntu for a decent period.

Long story short I have gotten used to almost all the changes, except for the keyboard. Specifically the keyboard shortcuts.

I quite liked the use of `super` key for bunch of shortcuts. It definitely was less stressful on my fingers than constantly using `ctrl`, among other things.

Anyways, to my chagrin I am finding it quite difficult to remap or additionally map "Super + (c, v, t, w, z, x, left, right)" shortcuts. These shortcuts are either applicable across different applications & are deemed sufficiently low level or they work on word-by-word level in a text box.

I tried using **xmodmap**, **xbindkeys**, **xdotool**, **AutoKey** without much luck.

I did have high hopes from **xmodmap** (it let me map **Super_L** as an additional **Ctrl** key, but that was problematic since now doing Super+Tab was switching tabs instead of switching applications).

Has anybody successfully re-mapped key combinations in Ubuntu (especially for versions where Wayland/Gnome 3 is used)?

At the minimum I want to be able to `Super + (c, v, t, w, z, x, left, right)`

Comment: What exactly (I assume Super + ...) do you want to remap to what else? Most defined Super combinations are at the level of the desktop environment, so they can be changed there. Capslock can be made in an additional Control key, if the prime aim is to reach that key easier.

Comment: Yes, I want to use super with c, v, w, y, x. Where are they defined at the desktop env?